# Как сделать ограничения на вводимые символы в input в react

Tags: reactjs

Как правильно сделать ограничения на вводимые символы в input в react?
Нужно запретить все символы кроме русских букв, английских букв, знаков ,._-=?! ,цифр, ограничить кол-во символов и запретить вводить пробелы в начале.

Вот, что у меня получилось

```
        if (e.target.value.length <= 25) {
            var regexp = /^[a-zа-яё,._\-/=!?1-90\s]+$/i;
            if(regexp.test(e.target.value)) {
                this.setState({filter_search: e.target.value});
            }
        }
```

Вроде все работает, но теперь нельзя удалить последний символ в строке. И не понятно как запретить пробелы в начале строки и двойные пробелы.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/nicolaa/63qk9dmj/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите проверки. Из-за них не срабатывает `setState` и вы не можете изменить значение при некоторых условиях. Просто вырезайте ненужные символы и устанавливайте первые 25 символов как значение вместо проверки длины. `setState` должен выполниться в любом случае

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filter_search: ''
    }
    this.onChangeSearch = this.onChangeSearch.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeSearch(e) {
    let regexp = /[^a-zа-яё,._\-\/=\!\?0-9\s]/gi;
    let value = e.target.value;
    value = value.replace(/^\s/, '');
    value = value.replace(/  /, ' ');
    value = value.replace(regexp, '');
    value = value.substr(0, 25);
    this.setState({
      filter_search: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <input 
          value = {this.state.filter_search}
          onChange = {this.onChangeSearch}
        /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < TodoApp / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно всего лишь добавить проверку на пустое значение. Перепишите ваше условие вот так:

```
const value = e.target.value;
if (value.length <= 25) {
   var regexp = /^[a-zа-яё,._\-/=!?1-90\s]+$/i;
   if(!value || regexp.test(value)) {
       this.setState({filter_search: value});
   }
}
```

Comment: В том то и ошибка)) Когда удаляете последний символ, то в `target.value` приходит `''`. Условие не выполняется, setState не выполняется, в итоге последний символ в строке не удаляется

Comment: @DmitryKozlov это понятно:) я думал просто что человеку нужно показать где проблема в его коде:) На самом деле я тоже пользуюсь подходом как и у вас:)